# React Native - How to prevent re-render an "static" component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm having a little issue here, trying to update a component using UseEffect React Hook, it ended rendering the whole parent component as well.

I reduce my code to this example, but still cannot find a solution. I don't understand why every time I change the "previewVisible" state, it renders the "Greeting" component. Already tried with UseCallback, memo, UseMemo ... I don't know what I am missing here.

```
  const [previewVisible, setPreviewVisible] = useState(false);
  const Greeting = React.memo(function Greeting({ name }) {
    console.log(Math.random(), "render");
    return <Text>{name}</Text>;
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Greeting name={"bla bla bla"} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setPreviewVisible(!previewVisible)}>
        <Text>Press me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {previewVisible && <ModalPreview />}
    </View>
  );
};
```

In this example, I want to show or hide the "ModalPreview" but no render the Greeting component itself.

Comment: move the Greeting component outside the function and it will work , dont keep it inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the greeting component implementation out of the parent component.

```
const App = () => {
const [previewVisible, setPreviewVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <Greeting name={"bla bla bla"} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setPreviewVisible(!previewVisible)}>
        <Text>Press me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {previewVisible && <ModalPreview />}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Now you don't even need to use a memo, unless you want to use it multiple times with different props.

```
  const Greeting = ({ name }) => {
    console.log(Math.random(), "render");
    return <Text>{name}</Text>;
  };
```

Comment: Worked great on the example, and also on the real case. I have a real mess with children component's declared inside parent's. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Move the Greeting function with memo outside the parent function

snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/4903ce

```
const Greeting = React.memo(function Greeting({ name }) {
  console.log(Math.random(), 'render');
  return <Text>{name}</Text>;
});

export default function App() {
  const [previewVisible, setPreviewVisible] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <Greeting name={'bla bla bla'} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setPreviewVisible(!previewVisible)}>
        <Text>Press me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {previewVisible && <View />}
    </View>
  );
}
```